# rails- devise - can't log out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I can't test my login... 'cos I can't logout (haven't put the logout button there yet).
I was able to test it once but now I am 'stuck' logged in!

How come I can't use
`http://localhost:3000/account/sign_out`

and I get an error `No route matches [GET] "/account/sign_out"`

but `rake routes` gives me:

```
         ...
         new_standard_user_session GET    /account/sign_in(.:format)                                      devise/sessions#new
             standard_user_session POST   /account/sign_in(.:format)                                      devise/sessions#create
     destroy_standard_user_session DELETE /account/sign_out(.:format)                                     devise/sessions#destroy    new_standard_user_registration GET    /account/sign_up(.:format)                                      devise/registrations#new
             ...
```

and my `/account/sign_in` and `/account_sign_up` url's are ok

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
No route matches [GET] "/account/sign_out"
```

You tried to access that link via a GET method, but your route is DELETE, as you've posted.

```
destroy_standard_user_session DELETE /account/sign_out(.:format)
```

So, to make that work, use the `method` parameter from `link_to` (I'm supposing you're creating your link with `link_to`)

Something like this

```
link_to "Sign Out", destroy_standard_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

Best regards

Comment: Yup, that's it, Added the link with the :delete fixed it. thx.